# Multiple session are not allowed with single user Id

Tags: jmeter

I am giving no.of users as 10 in thread group. All the 10 users will use only one login id. But only first user is able to login to the application and remaining 9 users are getting failed as they are not able to login.(I can login multiple times in different browsers with same user id) But if I give 10 different user ids then 10 users can be logged in. Please tell me what I can suggest to the developer in this regard. I know this is not IP blocking (because I can login lot many times from same IP with different user ids) and IP spoofing is not the approach to overcome this. Dev team is not able to provide much user ids so they have to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running 10 threads? did you make sure user 2-10 can login ?

Comment: Yes. 2 users also not able to login with same user id. For testing purpose, I have to login multiple times with a same user Id

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the use a CSV Dataset Config to use a single login per user. This way you can simulate [multiple user login with JMeter](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/12/14/multiple-user-login-jmeter/).

The idea is to define the logins and password in a CSV file. Then, using those variables, the user logs in on the system. This way, you have only one login per concurrent user.

Comment: In that case I need to have more no.of login credentials (e.g. 10 credentials for 10 users) right? But we have less no.of credentials than what we required.

Comment: You need one login per concurrent user if your application doesn't allow more than 1 user with the same login.

Comment: Yes,  Please tell me what I can suggest to the developer so that they can disable the restriction which is causing the issue?

Comment: Ask as many test accounts as concurrent users you need to simulate.

Comment: Ok. But I just want to know, Is there any session management from the application side which is causing the issue?

Comment: Only the developer can tell you how the session management works on server side. I can't see the code myself.

Comment: Usually which mechanism sets this kind of restrictions from the application side?

Comment: I don't know, I've developed many web applications but I have never experienced such issues. Sometimes, applications are simply designed to prevent one user login multiple times for security / concurrency reasons.